# ¿Como puedo mockear con mocha y sinon un servicio con la siguiente linea "res.status(200).json(data)"?

Tags: testing, mocha, mock

quizas la pregunta para alguien con cierta experiencia en testing, suponga algo basico, pero la verdad estoy tratando de aprender testing en back y me esta suponiendo una tortura, para empezar los tutoriales en si de mocha la mayoría son muy muy basicos y los pocos que he encontrado por ejemplo en udemy cada uno tienen el mismo problema no explica como enfrentarse a las miles de maneras que puede el back devolver los datos suponen que se devolvera de una forma muy concreta y te tienes que ajustar con ella.

El servicio que estoy intentando mockear es un controlador con las siguientes instrucciones

```
exports.getUserById = (req, res) => {

    // User.findById(req.params.id).exec((err, data) => { })

    User.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).json(data)
        })
        .catch(err => handleError(err, res))
}
```

He intentado mockearlo de la siguiente forma

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.use(sinonChai);

var moongose = require('mongoose');

var usersHandlers = require('./user-handler');
var usersModels = require('../models/user-model');
var errorHandlers = require('../helpers/handle-error');

const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');

var sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe('Test de usuarios',()=>{
    //declaro los elementos a usar
    let findByIDStub;
    let sampleUsers;

    beforeEach(()=>{
        sampleUsers = {
            first_name: 'first_name',
            last_name: 'last_name',
            password: 'password',
            age: 1,
            email: 'email',
            avatar: 'avatar',
            role: 'user'
        };
        
        findByIDStub = sandbox.stub(moongose.Model,'findById').resolves(sampleUsers);
        //findStub = sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model,'find');
    });

    afterEach(()=>{
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    context('get', (()=>{
        it('debería comprobar la id',()=>{
            let res1 = {
                statusCode:200,
                data:{},
                status:function(numero){
                    this.statusCode = numero
                    return this.statusCode;
                },
                json:function(data){
                    return this.data = data
                }
            }
            usersHandlers.getUserById({params:{id:-1}},res1);
            expect(res1.statusCode).to.be.equal(400);
        })
    }));
})
```

Sin embargo obtengo el siguiente fallo, "Test de usuarios
get
1) debería comprobar la id
TypeError: res.status(...).json is not a function
at C:\Users\K_H_S\OneDrive\Formacion\pruebasAngular\api-project\app\handlers\user-handler.js:67:29
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

0 passing (20ms)
1 failing

1. Test de usuarios
   get
   debería comprobar la id:

   AssertionError: expected 200 to equal 400

   - expected - actual

   -200
   +400

   at Context. (app\handlers\users-handlers.spec.js:59:43)
   at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
   "

y no se que hacer, he buscado varios casos con mensajes de error similares, pero no me funcionan y estoy algo perdido la verdad, antes de esto probe tal como aparecia en el curso que estoy siguiendo en ese en vez de con la forma mostrada, llamaba con un callback

pongo el código del it que es el que cambia

```
it('debería comprobar la id',()=>{
            usersHandlers.getUserById({params:{id:-1}},(err, res)=>{
                expect(err).to.exist;
                expect(result).to.not.exist;
                expect(errorHandlers).to.have.been.call();
                expect(err.status).to.equal(400);
                done();
            });
        })
```

En este caso el error es que no reconoce res.status

```
Test de usuarios
    get
      ✔ debería comprobar la id
TypeError: res.status is not a function
    at C:\Users\K_H_S\OneDrive\Formacion\pruebasAngular\api-project\app\handlers\user-handler.js:67:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)


  1 passing (20ms)
```

y no se ya como abarcarlo, si intento el camino del callback, tengo un problema, si lo ignoro tengo otro, además debo reconocer que no le termino de ver el sentido a que utilice resolve con un "usuario real" cuando al pasarle un id erroneo deberia resolver con un usuario falso, nuevamente como digo no lo explica el video y sin embargo cuando llama con el callback parece hacerlo correctamente, aunque luego falle por que no reconoce .status.

Comment: De tu código se desprende que has establecido el objeto de respuesta `res1` con la propiedad `status` a 200, y en el test estás esperando que el valor sea 400. Al parecer, no tienes completamente claro lo que vas a probar.

Comment: @Mauricio Concretas, lo tengo puesto así porque esperaba que al llamar al metodo este al tener un err.status(400).json(data) implicaría que se modificara, ya que el código en teoría debe fallar al pasarle como parametro un id:-1, aparte de eso principalmente el problema es que no sabia como resolver esas llamadas a status y json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras mucho buscar he encontrado una forma de mockear tanto el res como req, mi código ha quedado de la siguiente forma:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.use(sinonChai);

var usersHandlers = require('./user-handler');
var usersModels = require('../models/user-model');
var errorHandlers = require('../helpers/handle-error');

const mockRequest = (sessionData, body, params) => ({
    session: { data: sessionData },
    body,
    params
  });
  
  const mockResponse = () => {
    const res = {};
    res.status = sinon.stub().returns(res);
    res.json = sinon.stub().returns(res);
    return res;
  };


var sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

let usuarioEjemplo = {
    first_name: 'first_name',
    last_name: 'last_name',
    password: 'password',
    age: 1,
    email: 'email',
    avatar: 'avatar',
    role: 'user'
};

describe('Test de usuarios',()=>{
    beforeEach(()=>{
        handleErrorStub = sandbox.stub(errorHandlers,'handleError').callsFake((err, res)=>{
            return res.status(400).json({error: 'error falso'});
        });
        findByIdStub = sandbox.stub(usersModels,'findById');
    });

    afterEach(()=>{
        sandbox.restore();
        sinon.restore();
    });

    context('getById', (()=>{
        it('debería mostrar un error cuando la id es incorrecta', ()=>{
            const res = mockResponse();
            const req = mockRequest({},{},{id: -1});

            findByIdStub.rejects(new Error('error'), res);
            usersHandlers.getUserById(req,res);
            expect(findByIdStub).to.have.been.calledWith(-1);
            handleErrorStub(new Error(), res);
            expect(res.status).to.have.been.calledWith(400);
        })

        it('debería devolver un usuario cuando la id es correcta',()=>{
            //Comprobamos cuando el id es correcto
            const res = mockResponse();
            const req = mockRequest({},{},{id: 1});

            let fakeGetById = sinon.fake((id)=>{
                res.status(200).json(usuarioEjemplo);
            });

            sinon.replace(usersHandlers,'getUserById',fakeGetById);
            usersHandlers.getUserById(req.params.id);

            expect(fakeGetById).to.have.been.calledWith(1);
            expect(res.json).to.have.been.calledWith(usuarioEjemplo);
            expect(res.status).to.have.been.calledWith(200);
        })
    }));
})
```

espero sirva de ayuda por si alguien tiene la misma duda sobre como mockear este tipo de peticiones.